# does php function affects sub directories too?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i just made a view counter using PHP and MySql in index.php page of website which counts view each time the site is visited. but i noticed its also taking effect in sub directories visited. i just want to count view for website.com . note website.com/admin/admin.php

```
 $visitor=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

       $count = "select max(counts) as count_max_value from visitor";
       $countRun=mysqli_query($conn,$count);
       $countRow=mysqli_fetch_array($countRun);
               $current_counts=$countRow[0];
               $new_count=$current_counts+1;

        $remote_ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $visited=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $time=date("Y-m-d g:ia");


        $queryUpdate="INSERT INTO `visitor`(`counts`,`ip_address`,`url_visited`,`date`)VALUES('".$new_count."','".$remote_ip."','".$visited."','".$time."')";
        $runUpdate=mysqli_query($conn,$queryUpdate);


?>
```

Comment: there are two ways 
either put a check on url or put the code in section that is visible on home page only

Comment: can you please tell me how to check on url. because below answer is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You ONLY want to log visits to your homepage?

OK, as long as you understand that people can usually get to other pages (from links and search results) without ever visiting your homepage.

There's one catch, that apache will put the domain-name in the REQUEST_URI when it is in a VirtualHost.

#### If you're NOT on a VirtualHost

```
...
$time=date("Y-m-d g:ia");

if ($visited == '/' || empty($visted) {
    // log $visited here.
}
```

#### If you ARE

```
...
$time=date("Y-m-d g:ia");

$site = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri = str_replace($site, '', $visited);
if ($uri == '/' || empty($uri) {
    // log $site here.
}
```

Comment: note, if you're seeing `website.com/path...` in your db, then you need the "If you ARE" option.

Comment: but what is empty($visited) for in if statement?

Comment: @judy, depending on your config, there may or may not be that trailing slash in `$uri`, thus a match can be `/` or empty-string.